# Why are the normals on my curve path not at each control point?

Tags: edit-mode, bezier-curves, vertices, normals

I am new to Blender and trying to develop a path that will be used to make a curved section of road. When I add the curve path and try to edit it, the normals are not at each of the control points but rather bunched up at the end of the path. I have tried resetting normals, still to no avail. Any advice? Picture of what I mean attached below:
[image: Normals at end of curve]

Edit:
I have attached my blend file. I am trying to make a curved road and all of the tutorials I saw online explained to use a Nurbs path that will be used as a modifier for a plane. Here, all I have done is add a curve and I am trying to edit its control points, but the normals for the curve are not along the curve, but rather bunched at the end. I have made no changes to the curve except add it to the scene and show normals from the overlays menu.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi Boogieman, so you are new to this forum. This is not a problem. But your question is. Why? because we don't know what you mean and it isn't clear what you mean. So if you are a beginner and have no idea, it is always a good idea to describe exactly and each step what you did to get your result. e.g. i added a curve, subdivided it 2 times and grabbed the first handle and rotated it by 90 degrees. And/or provide your blend file. So you should tap the edit button and improve your question so that it won't be closed soon.

Comment: I don't see your problem when opening your file. Make sure you download the latest version from https://www.blender.org/download/